# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at printing ticket

Tags: java, openbravo

Im having this hs_err_pid when I try to print a ticket from Openbravo POS:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x77036018, pid=3436, tid=1096
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x56018]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x04a13c00):  JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=1096, stack(0x04470000,0x044c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000004

Registers:
EAX=0x002f1488, EBX=0x002c8200, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x0000a202
ESP=0x044bf874, EBP=0x044bf89c, ESI=0x002f1480, EDI=0x00270000
EIP=0x77036018, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x044bf874)
0x044bf874:   00270000 002c8200 00000000 53944b40
0x044bf884:   0000000a 044bf868 00000000 044bf984
0x044bf894:   76ffe115 00149a2e 044bf994 77036287
0x044bf8a4:   00270000 002f1480 044bf964 00000000
0x044bf8b4:   735c7ef2 00000000 00270000 002c8208
0x044bf8c4:   77032fe7 735c7e2a 00000008 00270194
0x044bf8d4:   00270000 00360024 00000050 fffffffe
0x044bf8e4:   77032fe7 00270000 00275908 00340025 

Instructions: (pc=0x77036018)
0x77036008:   85 56 3b 03 00 8b 56 0c 8d 46 08 8b 08 89 4d f0
0x77036018:   8b 49 04 89 55 f4 8b 12 3b d1 0f 85 b7 55 fd ff 


Stack: [0x04470000,0x044c0000],  sp=0x044bf874,  free space=13e044bf390k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x56018]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x56287]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x565a6]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x4c484]
C  [crtdll.dll+0xc4d7]
j  gnu.io.LPRPort.writeArray([BII)V+0
j  gnu.io.LPRPort$ParallelOutputStream.write([B)V+26
j  com.openbravo.pos.printer.escpos.PrinterWritterRXTX.internalWrite([B)V+78
j  com.openbravo.pos.printer.escpos.PrinterWritter$1.run()V+8
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+59
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+28
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf049c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17fcf1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf0667]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf06dd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11a2a0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1ddb14]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17f96c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x4ee1c]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637eb]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637be]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  gnu.io.LPRPort.writeArray([BII)V+0
j  gnu.io.LPRPort$ParallelOutputStream.write([B)V+26
j  com.openbravo.pos.printer.escpos.PrinterWritterRXTX.internalWrite([B)V+78
j  com.openbravo.pos.printer.escpos.PrinterWritter$1.run()V+8
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+59
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+28
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x04acb000 JavaThread "Trident pulse source thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3124, stack(0x04620000,0x04670000)]
  0x04aca800 JavaThread "Trident callback thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3412, stack(0x045d0000,0x04620000)]
  0x04a16000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2432, stack(0x044c0000,0x04510000)]
=>0x04a13c00 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=1096, stack(0x04470000,0x044c0000)]
  0x0129b000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=4004, stack(0x00370000,0x003c0000)]
  0x01b8a000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=2116, stack(0x04140000,0x04190000)]
  0x01b89400 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2840, stack(0x040f0000,0x04140000)]
  0x01b88c00 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=3044, stack(0x040a0000,0x040f0000)]
  0x01b86800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3160, stack(0x04050000,0x040a0000)]
  0x01ae7800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2608, stack(0x03de0000,0x03e30000)]
  0x01ae2800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2476, stack(0x03d90000,0x03de0000)]
  0x01ae1800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2468, stack(0x03d40000,0x03d90000)]
  0x01ade800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2204, stack(0x03cf0000,0x03d40000)]
  0x01ad6800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4008, stack(0x03ca0000,0x03cf0000)]
  0x01ad2000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2976, stack(0x03c50000,0x03ca0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01ad0c00 VMThread [stack: 0x01240000,0x01290000] [id=2728]
  0x01af1c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x03e30000,0x03e80000] [id=3768]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 8320K, used 1394K [0x23ac0000, 0x243c0000, 0x29010000)
  eden space 7424K,  10% used [0x23ac0000, 0x23b8ac98, 0x24200000)
  from space 896K,  65% used [0x24200000, 0x24291f48, 0x242e0000)
  to   space 896K,   0% used [0x242e0000, 0x242e0000, 0x243c0000)
 tenured generation   total 18344K, used 16823K [0x29010000, 0x2a1fa000, 0x33ac0000)
   the space 18344K,  91% used [0x29010000, 0x2a07dc38, 0x2a07de00, 0x2a1fa000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 10625K [0x33ac0000, 0x346c0000, 0x37ac0000)
   the space 12288K,  86% used [0x33ac0000, 0x345207e8, 0x34520800, 0x346c0000)
    ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x37ac0000, 0x37feae00, 0x37feae00, 0x384c0000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x384c0000, 0x38b572d8, 0x38b57400, 0x390c0000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
0x76fe0000 - 0x7711c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x75810000 - 0x758e4000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75140000 - 0x7518b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x77130000 - 0x771d0000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76b00000 - 0x76bac000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x767c0000 - 0x767d9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x769f0000 - 0x76a92000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x75710000 - 0x757d9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x767e0000 - 0x7682e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x75410000 - 0x7541a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x76880000 - 0x7691d000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x756f0000 - 0x7570f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76920000 - 0x769ec000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6da97000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x72780000 - 0x727b2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x74f30000 - 0x74f7c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d290000 - 0x6d298000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x75360000 - 0x75365000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6d7ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x70320000 - 0x70371000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x76e80000 - 0x76fdc000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x73e60000 - 0x73ffe000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x76aa0000 - 0x76af7000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x739b0000 - 0x739c3000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x73ce0000 - 0x73d20000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x74f80000 - 0x74f8c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x771d0000 - 0x77205000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x75370000 - 0x75376000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x74a30000 - 0x74a6c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x74a20000 - 0x74a26000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x72520000 - 0x72530000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x6f420000 - 0x6f430000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x6f400000 - 0x6f412000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x748f0000 - 0x74934000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x6f3f0000 - 0x6f3f8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x74580000 - 0x74585000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x72320000 - 0x7233c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x72310000 - 0x72317000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x6fbb0000 - 0x6fbb6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x72230000 - 0x72268000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x74a70000 - 0x74a86000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x74810000 - 0x7484b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x74650000 - 0x74667000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75000000 - 0x7500b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x75b70000 - 0x767ba000     C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll
0x6d230000 - 0x6d284000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x6d630000 - 0x6d639000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x6d1a0000 - 0x6d1c3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\dcpr.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10012000     C:\Sistematpv\app\OpenbravoPOS\OpenbravoPOS\lib\Windows\i368-mingw32\rxtxSerial.dll
0x6c240000 - 0x6c267000     C:\Windows\system32\crtdll.dll
0x75380000 - 0x7540f000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.DLL
0x012c0000 - 0x012cd000     C:\Sistematpv\app\OpenbravoPOS\OpenbravoPOS\lib\Windows\i368-mingw32\rxtxParallel.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=C:\Sistematpv\app\OpenbravoPOS\OpenbravoPOS\lib/Windows/i368-mingw32;C:\Sistematpv\app\OpenbravoPOS\OpenbravoPOS\lib/Windows/jacob -Ddirname.path=C:\Sistematpv\app\OpenbravoPOS\OpenbravoPOS\./ 
java_command: com.openbravo.pos.forms.StartPOS C:\Sistematpv\app\OpenbravoPOS\openbravopos.properties
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin
USERNAME=Utilisateur
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 2027120k(1262220k free), swap 4054240k(3091592k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.3-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_20-b02), built on Apr 12 2010 13:52:23 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Wed Apr 23 12:41:52 2014
elapsed time: 16 seconds
```

I tried a all I know and all I searched.
Changing the ntdll.dll , kerne32.dll and ctrdll.dll from mine (Cause this problem is only running in a PC that's not mine, and the proyect is running well in others 86 pc's)

I updated java, and followed all this points to help:

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/ntdlldll.htm

For more information:

Windows 7 32 bits
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

and the printer is an EPSON TM88T IV using LPT port.
It's a virtual port that epson creates itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem than jvm send when executes any functionality of the native code.

Maybe your problem comes caused by the use of the rxtx libraries, so i reccomend you to change the 'serial' into 'file' of the printer mode.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an USB smartcard reader. The Java program can connect, but attempts to transmit usually fail (almost all the time) with this error. Since this is not a printer, would changing to 'file' mode even make sense? (ignoring that I don't yet know how I can do that).